# redirecting to a route and sending a json response when password is match

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

i want to redirect to a route and then want to send a json message 
when i use this code `res.redirect('/signin').json({msg:"successfully register"})` when a password is match in my nodejs app

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=> {
  bcrypt.hash(newuser.password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
    if(err) throw err
    newuser.password=hash
    newuser.save()
      .then(person=>res.redirect('/signin').json({msg:"successfully register"}))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  });
});
```

expected output is that it should redirect to /signin page and should send a json message but it is only sending the json response.

Comment: Not possible. Is there any particular reason why you're trying this way? you want to utilize the `json` somewhere?

Comment: i was learning and  i use this code , but according to this code it should redirect and send the json response but why it is not happening

Comment: you should either `redirect` or send `json`, both cannot happen at same time

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer